# Click a Html Button using HtmlUnit in Java

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am currently developing a system. I need to click a website button using Java. So I am using **HtmlUnit** Library. There is a website called https://tempmail.ninja/ that generates temporary emails. What I need is program to click the Generate button in **tempmail.ninja** and it generates a temporary email. But the problem is it is not clicking. Not generating the email.

Here is my code What I have tried,

```
    try
    {
       WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
       webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
       webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
       webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
       webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
       webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
       HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://tempmail.ninja");

       //Here is button id. Instead of this I used HtmlAnchor, HtmlSubmitInput and etc.
       //But any of those didn't work         
       HtmlButton htmlButton = page.getHtmlElementById("generaEmailTemporal");
       htmlButton.click();

       webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(5000 * 2);   

       //Print the generated email but Currently nothing display
       HtmlTextInput htmlTextInput = (HtmlTextInput) page.getElementById("emailtemporal");
       System.out.println(htmlTextInput.getText());

       webClient.close();

    } catch(ElementNotFoundException | FailingHttpStatusCodeException | IOException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(WebTesting.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Here is the HTML code for the button. I get this using Inspect Element.

```
<p class="text-center" id="btnGeneraEmailTemporal">
<button class="btn btn-labeled btn-primary" id="generaEmailTemporal" type="button">
<span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> Generate Temp Mail
</button>
</p>
```

I am newbie to HtmlUnit. So Can anybody help me? I really appreciate that.
Thanks for your Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by using Selenium Web Driver. Used selenium to click the button and generate the email and pass it to the HtmlUnit.

Answer (score 0):

The .click() returns the changed page. So you should o something like this:

```
   HtmlButton htmlButton =  page.getHtmlElementById("generaEmailTemporal");
   HtmlPage pageAfterClick = (HtmlPage)htmlButton.click();
   webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(5000 * 2);      
   System.out.println(pageAfterClick.asXml()); // often displaying the page-source is more useful during development than .asText()
```

since `waitForBackgroundJavaScript(..)` is experimental and does not always work, I prefer polling until an expected text appears.

```
private static final int AJAX_MAX_TRIES_SECONDS = 30;
private static final int ONE_SEC_IN_MILLISEC = 1000;

/** Waits until the given 'text' appeared or throws an
 * WaitingForAjaxTimeoutException if the 'text' does not appear before we timeout.
 * @param page
 * @param text The text which indicates that ajax has finished updating the page
 * @param waitingLogMessage Text for the log-output. Should indicate where in the code we are, and what are we waiting for
 * @throws WaitingForAjaxTimeoutException
 */
public static void waitForAjaxCallWaitUntilTextAppears(//
        @Nonnull final HtmlPage page, //
        @Nonnull final String text, //
        @Nonnull final String waitingLogMessage)  {
    LOGGER.debug("_5fd3fc9247_ waiting for ajax call to complete ... [" + waitingLogMessage + "]");
    final StringBuilder waitingdots = new StringBuilder("   ");
    for (int i = 0; i < AJAX_MAX_TRIES_SECONDS; i++) {

        if (page.asText().contains(text)) {
            waitingdots.append(" ajax has finished ['").append(text).append("' appeared]");
            LOGGER.debug("_8cd5a34faf_ " + waitingdots);
            return;
        }
        waitingdots.append('.');
        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < ONE_SEC_IN_MILLISEC) {
            try {
                o.wait(ONE_SEC_IN_MILLISEC);
            }
            catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                // ignore
            }
        }

    }
    LOGGER.debug("_de5091bc9e_ "
            + waitingdots.append(" ajax timeout ['").append(text).append("' appeared NOT]").toString());
    LOGGER.debug("_f1030addf1_ page source:\n" + page.asXml());
    throw new RuntimeException("_ec3df4f228_");
}
```

Comment: Still nothing happens sir.

Comment: No error messages at all? Is the displayed `pageAfterClick.asXml()` the same as `page.asXml()` ?

Comment: You could try an other browser (that sometimes helps) (no idea why). ’waitForBackgroundJavaScript(long timeoutMillis)’ is experimental, maybe you should wait in a different way.

Comment: The website also implements some kind of add-blocker detection. So maybe that collides with your attempt too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it didn't help. Now I solved the problem using Selenium.